# Android Studio 2.1.1 emulator error

Tags: android, android-studio, emulation

I am learning the basics of Android programming. I tried to emulate my test app  and got following error. I am emulating using API 23, Android 6.0 ( Marshmallow) and getting the same error when emulating for Nexus 5 or 4. what should I do?

**Error Message:**

> Cannot launch AVD in emulator. Output: emulator: WARNING: VM heap size
>   set below hardware specified minimum of 128MB init: Could not find
>   wglGetExtensionsStringARB! emulator: WARNING: Setting VM heap size to
>   384MB getGLES1ExtensionString: Could not find GLES 1.x config! Hax is
>   enabled Failed to obtain GLES 1.x extensions string! Hax ram_size
>   0x60000000 HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode. Could
>   not initialize emulated framebufferaudio: Failed to create voice
>   `goldfish_audio_in' qemu-system-i386.exe: warning: opening audio input
>   failed adb_server_notify: Failed to establish connection to ADB server
>   console on port 5554, ADB on port 5555 emulator: ERROR: Could not
>   initialize OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu off' to disable it.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the 'Graphics' option to "Software- GLES 2.0" has worked for me.

Comment: Please don't add "thanks" as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](//stackoverflow.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, which is the Stack Overflow way of saying thank you.